# Losing information after converting from factor to numeric in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in which some of the numeric column are in factor and i want to convert to numeric value. However i tried the below code but still it is losing the information.

```
> str(xdate1)
    'data.frame':   6 obs. of  1 variable:
     $ Amount.in.doc..curr.: Factor w/ 588332 levels "-0.5","-1","-1,000",..: 5132 57838 81064 98277 76292 71982
```

```
After converting to numeric i am losing the information. below is the output:
```

```
    > xdate1$Amount.in.doc..curr.<-as.numeric(as.character(xdate1$Amount.in.doc..curr.))
    Warning message:
    NAs introduced by coercion 
    > str(xdate1)
    'data.frame':   6 obs. of  1 variable:
     $ Amount.in.doc..curr.: num  -150 NA NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have values with commas( `','`) which turn into `NA` when changing to numeric, remove them before converting to numeric.

```
xdate1$Amount.in.doc..curr. <- as.numeric(gsub(',', '', xdate1$Amount.in.doc..curr.))
```

Or use `parse_number` from `readr`

```
xdate1$Amount.in.doc..curr. <- readr::parse_number(as.character(xdate1$Amount.in.doc..curr.))
```